# Which path to use in itemPath?

Tags: yql

When creating a YQL table, one has to specify an **itemPath** in the  element of the table. According to the [YQL documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-reference.html#yql-opentables-select) this itemPath should contain:

> A dot-path that points to where the repeating data elements occur in the response format. These are the "rows" of your table.

If I specify the **itemPath** like this then I would "loose" some data in certain situation. e.g. in the example below I would loose the following key/value pairs:

- response => perpage, total, last_offset, page, window, offset, hidden
- request => all key/value pairs are lost

Some of these keys are maybe not that interesting because they are used for pagination only but I might still be interested in some of them e.g. **total**.

So my question is:

Should I in this situation just specify the itemPath `json.response` which will give me the whole response, or should I specify `json.response.list` which will only give me the items in the list but I have to accept to loose some data?

### Example:

http://otter.topsy.com/experts.xml?q=nosql

You will get an response like this:

```
{"response"=>
  {"list"=>
    [{"topsy_author_url"=>"http://topsy.com/twitter/al3xandru",
      "hits"=>819,
      "name"=>"Alex Popescu",
      "nick"=>"al3xandru",
      "url"=>"http://twitter.com/al3xandru",
      "photo_url"=>
       "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1260935149/carmel_head_sk_sm_normal.jpg",
      "influence_level"=>"10",
      "description"=>
       "Founder/CTO InfoQ.com, Software architect, Web aficionado, Speaker, NOSQL Dreamer http://nosql.mypopescu.com"},
     {"topsy_author_url"=>"http://topsy.com/twitter/rgaidot",
      "hits"=>957,
      "name"=>"R\303\251gis Gaidot",
      "nick"=>"rgaidot",
      "url"=>"http://twitter.com/rgaidot",
      "photo_url"=>
       "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1266738841/avatar-6_normal.jpg",
      "influence_level"=>"10",
      "description"=>"digital/technology enthusiast"},
     ...],
   "perpage"=>15,
   "total"=>113105,
   "last_offset"=>18,
   "page"=>1,
   "window"=>"a",
   "offset"=>0,
   "hidden"=>1},
 "request"=>
  {"response_type"=>"json",
   "resource"=>"experts",
   "parameters"=>{"q"=>"nosql"},
   "url"=>"http://otter.topsy.com/experts.json?q=nosql"}}
```

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you need the data returned to be small, it might be a good idea to streamline the data. You could also `delete` variables that you don't need. Just by doing `delete response.list.perpage;` if you're using JavaScript in that table, right before doing `return response;`.

Answer (score 1):

Which `itemPath` you choose to use for your table depends on how the table is intended to be used.  If only the `response.list` information will ever be wanted, then set that as the `itemPath`. If the `request`, or non-`list`, information will be sometimes useful then broaden the path.

There is the option of adding a parameter to the table to allow consumers to specify the `itemPath`, like other tables do, and have it default to the most common use case. Alternatively, the table could allow some flag in the query that dictates whether to return just the list of results or the whole original response.

Personally, I would likely just go with `json.response.list`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. So I can say `<select itemPath="{itemPathSelector}"` or what is the syntax for that? I have not seen an example of that yet, so if you could point me to an example of it being used that would be great too.

Comment: I finished the YQL tables for this specific case. I eventually went with your proposal of using `json.response.list`. Still I am wondering how to specify the **itemPath** in the query. Could not find a YQL table that uses this.